# Ошибка NoSuchElementException: No line found Scanner

Tags: java

Посмотрите пожалуйста, может кто знает, как исправить "NoSuchElementException: No line found" ошибку. Когда я запускаю программу в IntelliJ на Java 17 на своем компьютере, то подобную ошибку не дает. Но когда преподаватель проверяет этот код и запускает на своем компьютере, а также когда я пробовала запустить код на Jdoodle (https://www.jdoodle.com/online-java-compiler/) то дает эту ошибку:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.util.NoSuchElementException: No line found
    at java.base/java.util.Scanner.nextLine(Scanner.java:1651)
    at Assembler.main(Assembler.java:34)
```

Программа:

```
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Assembler
{
   private static final boolean TEST_MODE = !true;
   private static final Map<String, Byte> opcodes = Map.of(
        "ADD", (byte) 0b100000
        , "AND", (byte) 0b100100
        , "ADDI", (byte) 0b001000
        , "ANDI", (byte) 0b001100
        , "BEQ", (byte) 0b000100
        , "LW", (byte) 0b100011
        , "SW", (byte) 0b101011
        , "SRL", (byte) 0b000010
        , "SLL", (byte) 0b000000
);

public static void main(String[] args)
{
    int count = 0;

    if (TEST_MODE)
    {
        testCases();
    } else
    {
        System.out.println("Assembler - name\n");
        System.out.println("*** Begin entering Assembler:\n");

        while (true)
        {
            var scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
            var line = scanner.nextLine();
            if (line.equalsIgnoreCase("HALT"))
            {
                break;
            }
            count++;
            System.out.println("***: " + String.format("%32s",
                    Integer.toBinaryString(make(line))).replace(" ", "0"));
        }

        System.out.println("\n*** Assembly complete. Program required " + count + " words of memory.");
    }
}

private static int make(String line)
{
    var parts = line.split("\\s+");
    var funct = parts[0];

    switch (funct)
    {
        case "ADD", "AND":
            return AddOrAnd(funct, parts[2], parts[3], parts[1]);
        case "ADDI", "ANDI":
            return AddiOrAndi(funct, parts[2], parts[1], parts[3]);
        case "BEQ":
            return Beq(funct, parts[1], parts[2], parts[3]);
        case "SW", "LW":
            return SwLw(funct, parts[3], parts[1], parts[2]);
        case "SLL", "SRL":
            return Sll(funct, "0", parts[2], parts[1], parts[3]);

        default:
            throw new UnsupportedOperationException(funct);
    }
}

private static int SwLw(String funct, String rs, String rt, String im)
{
    var n = makeI(opcodes.get(funct), regToByte(rs), regToByte(rt), Short.parseShort(im));
    return n;
}

private static int Sll(String funct, String rs, String rt, String rd, String sa)
{
    var n = makeR((byte) 0, Byte.parseByte(rs), regToByte(rt), regToByte(rd), Byte.parseByte(sa), opcodes.get(funct));
    return n;
}

private static int Beq(String funct, String rs, String rt, String im)
{
    return makeI(opcodes.get(funct), regToByte(rs), regToByte(rt), Short.parseShort(im));
}

private static int AddiOrAndi(String funct, String rs, String rt, String im)
{

    return makeI(opcodes.get(funct), regToByte(rs), regToByte(rt), Short.parseShort(im));
}

private static int AddOrAnd(String func, String rs, String rt, String rd)
{
    var opcode = (byte) 0;
    var sa = (byte) 0;
    return makeR(opcode, regToByte(rs), regToByte(rt), regToByte(rd), sa, opcodes.get(func));
}

private static int makeR(byte opcode, byte rs, byte rt, byte rd, byte shiftAmount, byte funct)
{
    int returnValue = (opcode << 26) + (rs << 21) + (rt << 16) + (rd << 11) + (shiftAmount << 6) + funct;
    return returnValue;
}

private static int makeI(byte opcode, byte rs, byte rt, short immed)
{
    int intImmed = immed;
    if (immed == -1)
    {
        intImmed = (immed >>> (Short.BYTES * Short.SIZE - 16));
    }

    int returnValue = (opcode << 26) + (rs << 21) + (rt << 16) + intImmed;
    return returnValue;
}

private static byte regToByte(String r)
{
    byte returnValue = 0;
    String upperCase = r.toUpperCase();

    switch (upperCase) {
        case "$AT":
            returnValue = 1;
            break;
        case "$ZERO":
            returnValue = 0;
            break;
        case "$V0":
            returnValue = 2;
            break;
        case "$V1":
            returnValue = 3;
            break;
        case "$A0":
            returnValue = 4;
            break;
        case "$A1":
            returnValue = 5;
            break;
        case "$A2":
            returnValue = 6;
            break;
        case "$A3":
            returnValue = 7;
            break;
        case "$T0":
            returnValue = 8;
            break;
        case "$T1":
            returnValue = 9;
            break;
        case "$T2":
            returnValue = 10;
            break;
        case "$T3":
            returnValue = 11;
            break;
        case "$T4":
            returnValue = 12;
            break;
        case "$T5":
            returnValue = 13;
            break;
        case "$T6":
            returnValue = 14;
            break;
        case "$T7":
            returnValue = 15;
            break;
        case "$T8":
            returnValue = 24;
            break;
        case "$T9":
            returnValue = 25;
            break;
        case "$S0":
            returnValue = 16;
            break;
        case "$S1":
            returnValue = 17;
            break;
        case "$S2":
            returnValue = 18;
            break;
        case "$S3":
            returnValue = 19;
            break;
        case "$S4":
            returnValue = 20;
            break;
        case "$S5":
            returnValue = 21;
            break;
        case "$S6":
            returnValue = 22;
            break;
        case "$S7":
            returnValue = 23;
            break;
    }
    return returnValue;
}

/*************************************************************
 *
 *   Test Code below
 *   Do NOT modify
 *
 ************************************************************/
private static void tests_make()
{

    test_make("ADD $v0 $v1 $zero", 0b00000000011000000001000000100000);
    test_make("AND $a0 $a1 $a2", 0b00000000101001100010000000100100);
    // test_make("ADDI $a3 $t4 -321", 0b00100001100001111111111010111111);
    test_make("ADDI $a3 $t4 3", 0b00100001100001110000000000000011);

    test_make("ANDI $t0 $t5 123", 0b00110001101010000000000001111011);
    test_make("BEQ $s0 $t1 +517", 0b00010010000010010000001000000101);
    // test_make("LW $s1 -12 $t2", 0b10001101010100011111111111110100);
    test_make("LW $s1 12 $t2", 0b10001101010100010000000000001100);

    test_make("SW $s2 20 $t3", 0b10101101011100100000000000010100);
    test_make("SRL $a2 $a3 3", 0b00000000000001110011000011000010);
    test_make("SLL $a3 $a2 31", 0b00000000000001100011111111000000);
}

private static boolean test_make(String cmd, int expected)
{
    // funct rd rs rt
    var n = make(cmd);
    var a = Integer.toBinaryString(n);

    if (n != expected)
    {
        System.out.println("make failed for " + cmd);
        return false;
    }

    return true;
}

private static void testCases()
{
    tests_make();

    if (test_regToByte())
        System.out.println("RegToByte working well\n");
    else
        System.out.println("RegToByte failed\n");

    if (test_makeR())
        System.out.println("makeR working well\n");
    else
        System.out.println("makeR failed\n");

    if (test_makeI())
        System.out.println("makeI working well\n");
    else
        System.out.println("makeI failed\n");
}

private static boolean test_regToByte() {
    boolean passedTest = true;
    String[] regs = {"$ZERO", "$AT", "$V0", "$V1", "$A0", "$A1", "$A2", "$A3", "$T0", "$T1", "$T2", "$T3", "$T4",
            "$T5", "$T6", "$T7", "$S0", "$S1", "$S2", "$S3", "$S4", "$S5", "$S6", "$S7", "$T8", "$T9"};

    for (int i = 0; i < regs.length; i++) {
        passedTest &= testReg(regs[i], i);
    }

    return passedTest;
}

private static boolean testReg(String regName, int expValue) {
    if (regToByte(regName) != expValue)
        System.out.printf("Fail: regToByte(\"%s\") = %d, should be %d\n", regName, regToByte(regName), expValue);
    return regToByte(regName) == expValue;
}

private static boolean test_makeR() {
    boolean passedTest = true;
    int i = makeR((byte) 1, (byte) 1, (byte) 1, (byte) 1, (byte) 1, (byte) 1);
    if (i != 0b00000100001000010000100001000001) {
        System.out.println("Test: makeR(1,1,1,1,1,1) = " + Integer.toBinaryString(i) + " failed");
        passedTest = false;
    }

    i = makeR((byte) 63, (byte) 0, (byte) 31, (byte) 0, (byte) 31, (byte) 0);
    if (i != 0b11111100000111110000011111000000) {
        System.out.println("Test: makeR(63,0,31,0,31,0) = " + Integer.toBinaryString(i) + " failed");
        passedTest = false;
    }

    return passedTest;
}

private static boolean test_makeI() {
    boolean passedTest = true;
    int i = makeI((byte) 1, (byte) 1, (byte) 1, (short) 1);
    if (i != 0b00000100001000010000000000000001) {
        System.out.println("Test: makeI(1,1,1,1) = " + Integer.toBinaryString(i) + " failed");
        passedTest = false;
    }

    i = makeI((byte) 63, (byte) 0, (byte) 31, (short) 0);
    if (i != 0b11111100000111110000000000000000) {
        System.out.println("Test: makeI(63,0,31,0) = " + Integer.toBinaryString(i) + " failed");
        passedTest = false;
    }

    i = makeI((byte) 63, (byte) 0, (byte) 31, (short) -1);
    if (i != 0b11111100000111111111111111111111) {
        System.out.println("Test: makeI(63,0,31,-1) = " + Integer.toBinaryString(i) + " failed");
        passedTest = false;
    }

    return passedTest;
}
}
```

**Input:**

```
ADD $v0 $v1 $zero
AND $a0 $a1 $a2
ADDI $a3 $t4 -321
ANDI $t0 $t5 123
BEQ $s0 $t1 +517
LW $s1 -12 $t2
SW $s2 20 $t3
SRL $a2 $a3 3
SLL $a3 $a2 31
HALT
```

**Output:**

```
***: 00000000011000000001000000100000
***: 00000000101001100010000000100100
***: 00100001100001111111111010111111
***: 00110001101010000000000001111011
***: 00010010000010010000001000000101
***: 10001101010100011111111111110100
***: 10101101011100100000000000010100
***: 00000000000001110011000011000010
***: 00000000000001100011111111000000
*** Assembly complete. Program required 9 words of memory.
```

Comment: at Assembler.main(Assembler.java:34)   ------  34 СТРОЧКА это  var line = scanner.nextLine();

Answer (score 1, accepted):

При работе с вводом/выводом через стандартный поток ввода на сайте `jdoodle.com` следует включить интерактивный режим при помощи переключателя `Interactive`, но при этом вставка через буфер при помощи Ctrl+V / Shift+Ins работать не будет, команды ассемблера придётся печатать вручную:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

В неинтерактивном режиме знаки доллара в аргументах ассемблерных команд нужно заэкранировать при помощи `\`

```
ADD \$v0 \$v1 \$zero
AND \$a0 \$a1 \$a2
ADDI \$a3 \$t4 -321
ANDI \$t0 \$t5 123
BEQ \$s0 \$t1 +517
LW \$s1 -12 \$t2
SW \$s2 20 \$t3
SRL \$a2 \$a3 3
SLL \$a3 \$a2 31
HALT
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

---

Также следует отметить, что создание экземпляра сканера нужно вынести из цикла `while`:

```java
var scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
while (true) {
    var line = scanner.nextLine();
// ...
}
```